# Is the atlas containing only the chart (R, cube root) for a manifold (R, standard) a C^infinity? why?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

Let A={(R,cube root)} be an atlas for a manifold(R, standard topology).There is only one chart and no other in the atlas. Is the atlas C^infinity compatible? and why so?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yes, there's only one chart and so no smoothness conditions to check. The resulting smooth structure is different from but isomorphic to the usual smooth structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differentiable class of a Differentiable Manyfold is referenced a change parameters funcions. In this case, has "only" change parameters, in fact, the identity function over $\mathbb{R}$. Clearly, this function is $C^\infty$.